# how to use multiple preloaders in a same page for different actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

I am trying to use multiple preloaders that can be loaded only in the particular area of the page instead of loading for the whole page and also during the occurrence of different events like button click.

The code I used is:

**HTML**

```
<style>
.preload div#preloader { 
     position: fixed; 
     left: 0; 
     top: 0; 
     z-index: 999; 
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%; 
     overflow: visible; 
     background: #3C3D3F url('../images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center; 
 }
</style>
<div class="preload">
    <div id="preloader">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
        $(window).load(function(){
                $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by modifying your CSS.

```
.preload div#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: #3C3D3F;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}
.preload div#preloader.type1 {
    background-image:url("img-one.gif");
}
.preload div#preloader.type2 {
    background-image:url("img-two.gif");
}
.preload div#preloader.type3 {
    background-image:url("img-three.gif");
}
```

Here, `type1,type2,type3` are just different classes which you can add/remove based on the event. You should have a mapping of class and event so that you can toggle the classes.

Comment: however this will load in the whole page but what i need is to load only in the particular section of the page. For eg: If a page has a left menu, header, body and footer I want my loader to be loaded only in the left menu area as the menus are getting collapsed.

Comment: You can configure that using CSS rules. That should not be a problem

Comment: Yes your are right but whats the use of configuring it with CSS. If i click the menus in the left menu it will get loaded again i.e. the left menu part. Once the left menu is loaded it should not be loaded again when the menus in it is clicked